# Multiline text view not showing the full text

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following layout with a LinearLayout that contains a Material ShapableImageView and a TextView. I need my TextView to take 2 lines if it's width is bigger than the ImageView's with, but I can't figure out how to do it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/company_card_layout"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_small"
  android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_small"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_small">

  <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
    android:id="@+id/category_logo"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_avatar_default_tinted"
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/AppTheme.ShapeableImageView.Squircle" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/category_name"
    style="@style/AppTheme.Text.Caption.Light.Darker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:text="This is a very long text and should take at least 2 lines" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is how it's currently being shown and as you can see, it doesn't show the full text:

[image]

Comment: why `tools:text` instead of `android:text`?

Comment: @snachmsm `tools:text` allows you to set text that is only rendered in the IDE layout preview. It's useful for these cases where you just want to fiddle with your layout without needing to run the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that you're limiting the width of your `LinearLayout` by the width of your image, you can set its width to the same, which should help. This allows the measure pass (I believe) to "better" define all the measure constraints/rules.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/company_card_layout"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
        android:id="@+id/category_logo"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/my_drawable" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="This is a very long text and should take at least 2 lines" />
</LinearLayout>
```